# browser query vs python MySQLdb query

Tags: php, python, mysql, pyqt4, mysql-python

I wanted to know whether mysql query with browser is faster or python's MySQLdb is faster. I am using MysqlDb with PyQt4 for desktop ui and PHP for web ui.

Comment: why i are you comparing such different things?

Comment: Make a testcase and find it out?

Comment: I am designing a new type of database using mysql as base. I have to make a ui for users to make things easy. So i had to decide whether to make a web ui or a desktop ui

Comment: depends on what you need, do you need users to have a web ui?.. on the other side you can make both..

Comment: As making a web application is much easier than making a desktop application.. I will make desktop version only if it is faster.

Comment: You're not going to see much speed advantage (if any) from building a Python desktop app, especially if you're more familiar with web development. I recommend creating a web application.

Also, your question doesn't make much sense - browsers don't directly interact with MySQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking about whether Python or PHP (what I think you mean by browser?) is more efficient at making a database call.

The answer? It depends on the specific code and calls, but it's going to be largely the same. Both Python and PHP are interpreted languages and interpret the code at run time. If either of the languages you were using were compiled (say, like, if you used C), I'd say you might see a speed advantage of one over the other, but with the current information you've given us, I can't really judge that.

I would use the language you are most comfortable in or feel would best fit the task - they're both going to connect to a MySQL database and do the same exact commands and queries, so just write the code in the easiest way possible for you to do it.

Also, your question as posed doesn't make much sense. Browsers don't interact with a MySQL database, PHP, which is executed by a server when you request a page, does.

Comment: "Both Python and PHP are interpreted languages and interpret the code at run time." It's... a little more complex than that.

Comment: I was trying to stay fairly simplistic (both because the OP seemed to be just starting out and also I didn't want to say anything incorrect, because my knowledge of the differences between interpreted and compiled languages is only so-so)

Comment: Fair enough. I just don't want anyone quoting it blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't perform database queries (unless you consider the embedded SQLite database), so not only is your question nonsensical, it is in fact completely irrelevant.